# My PC shuts down randomly without a warning

Tags: hardware-failure, shutdown, troubleshooting, desktop-computer

I have been dealing with this problem for quite some time now and it's starting to get really annoyning. The reason i'm asking on this forum is to find some sort of solution since my trouble shooting has not payed off. Since this issue seems to be happening at any giving time, it's really difficult to find the culprit.

It can shutdown whenever, and i have not been able to locate the reason behind it. First i ran a stress test on the CPU to check if it was heat related, but it ran smooth without a problem.
I also tried formatting my bootdrive without any luck.

Just to list things i havent yet been able to troubleshoot is a different CPU, RAM, PSU or Motherboard. Though i find it hard to believe that those are the case.
Something else i have noticed is that my fans are not always running at the same RPM. Sometimes after a reboot they will run silently and around same speeds, where as the PC will run with any issues for days. But whenever this issue do occur, i usually notice some of the fans or just one is going in different speed intervals(slowing down, then up and so on).

Heres my system specs:

- RYZEN 7 3800x - water cooled
- 16 GB DDR4 Corsair Vengeance
- GIGABYTE RTX 2080s
- ASUS X470-F
- 850W PSU

If this post lack any sort of information please let me know and i will update the thread.

Comment: Get memtest86.exe (Internet Search), make a bootable USB Key (Rufus). Start with that and test memory. Memory faults can cause what you see.  Test for rootkit viruses (TDSSKiller from Kaspersky).  Boot with another system on a USB key and see if it crashes that way (test for corrupted software).

Comment: Sometimes, this is due to PSU not being able to provide the power needed, 850W is big but your configuration might be asking for more.

Comment: I'll second user10191234--in my experience a dying power supply can cause sudden and inexplicable shutdowns.  I have yet to find any way to test for this short of swapping the supply--they deliver the proper voltages in a low power test, it's just when asked to deliver hundreds of watts something goes out of spec and trips the undervolt shutdown.

Comment: @John I did ran a test with the built-in memory test tool, without it finding any issues - should i also do it with memtest86?

Comment: That is the built-in memory test tool for windows i am talking about.

Comment: You should also try memtest86.exe along with the other thoughts here.